# How do I make DateEntry Dropdown that shows me a calendar

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbsNs.png)I'm creating an App where the user is meant to select date which is saved on a database

I'm using the DateEntry class in the Tkcalender module in python. When I use the drop_down function it does to drop down to show me a calendar the user can select from

```
self.lblDoB = Label(DataFrameLEFT, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), 
                    text="Date of Birth:", bg="Ghost white", 
                    padx=2,pady=2, )
        self.lblDoB.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        #self.ttkcal = Calender.Calendar(DataFrameLEFT, firstweekday=Calender.calendar.SUNDAY)
        self.ttkcal = DateEntry(DataFrameLEFT, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'))
        self.ttkcal.drop_down()
        self.ttkcal.grid(row =3, column=1)
```

It seems the `drop_down()` function does not work

Comment: in what way is it not working? Im a little confused by your wording...can you show us the output vs the desired output?

Comment: I need the date entry widget to drop down and show a calendar where the user can select a specific date and store it in a variable

Comment: and what is it actually doing? your sentence in your question explaining the behavior is grammatically incorrect and hard to understand

Comment: the drop down when clicked does not do anything